# Hibernate JPQL - querying for KEY() in Map association error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, jpql

I'm trying to make a JPQL query that should fetch an entity and the keys from one of its map associations, and I'm getting a bizzare error.

My setup is JPA2 using the Hibernate (3.5) implementation.

The model is as follows:

I have a Department entity bean such as:

```
@Entity
```

public class Department {

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="department_sequence", allocationSize=100)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DEPARTMENT_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
protected Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Map<String,Phone> phones = new HashMap<String, Phone>();
```

//... getters and setters follow

and it's associated entity :

```
@Entity
```

public class Phone {

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PHONE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="phone_sequence", allocationSize=100)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PHONE_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
protected Long id;
private int number;
```

//... getters and setters follow

Now I thought, as per the "Mastering JPA2..." book, that I could do a JPQL such as:

```
String queryString2 = "SELECT d, KEY(p) FROM Department d JOIN d.phones p WHERE p='internal'";
```

but all this gets me a bizzare error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode
```

-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'KEY' {originalText=KEY}
    -[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       -[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'phone2_.id' {alias=p, className=model.Phone, tableAlias=phone2_}

```
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:156)...
```

Can someone please tell me if the JPQ I'm using is wrong, and if so, what might be a correct alternative to getting an entity and ONLY the keys from one of its map associations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, this is because KEY & VALUE for maps are not implemented:
https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5396 I am not aware of alternative query.

Answer (score 4):

For next readers, the bug mentionned by Mikko Maunu has just been resolved yesterday, so we just need to wait the next release :)

Comment: Which was yesterday as well (4.1.4.Final)